# How to remove 08 hexadecimal character from an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, hex

I have a long string, and I would like to remove a specific hexadecimal character from it.

```
NSString * myString = @"longlongstringwithcharacters\"ofallsorts\"";
```

Any suggestions?

The hex character I am after is **08**, that corresponds to backspace. How can I use code like the following to substitute it? I have no idea on how to represent 08 in a string:

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

**EDIT:**

I will try to clarify a bit more what I am trying to do..

I am trying to remove all occurrences of a character that corresponds to 08 hex from the string that I receive as payload.

The payload is in a string format and I found out the character by using Xcode debugger and view the hex codes of the string as there was an invalid character when trying to covert the NSData corresponding to the string to a NSDictionary.

I am not sure how to phrase the problem correctly..

Comment: you have no such character in string

Comment: I am getting a JSON payload that contains an incorrect character (08 in hex) and I want to remove it before I convert it to a NSDictionary as it does not get recognised,  I convert it to NSData successfully but the 08 hex character is invalid. How can I substitute it?

Comment: Wait did you just say 08 is a **backspace** ? Didn't you mean a whitespace ? This got me confused in the first place

Comment: @Zil because this table suggest that 08 hex is backspace: http://www.nthelp.com/ascii.htm  is this incorrect?

Comment: Oh no certainly not, i'm just very surprised (kinda stumbled onto this question) that the backspace is actually a character. In my mind a character is something that is visible/printable ; I don't see how you can print a backspace ! :D
I guess I learned something today now didn't I ?

Comment: It is visible as it is interpreted by the software that handles the text as a newline and hence you just see the "newline effect". In ASCII code is referred as BS. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)stringFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {

    // The hex codes should all be two characters.
    if (([hexString length] % 2) != 0)
        return nil;

    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2) {

        NSString *hex = [hexString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        NSInteger decimalValue = 0;
        sscanf([hex UTF8String], "%x", &decimalValue);
        [string appendFormat:@"%c", decimalValue];
    }

    return string;
}
```

Try this code...This will help you to convert Hex to string

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * str = @"68656C6C6F";
NSMutableString * newString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
int i = 0;
while (i < [str length])
{
    NSString * hexChar = [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
    int value = 0;
    sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
    i+=2;
}
```

this will help u to convert Hex to NSString

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code seem a bit overkill for what I am trying to do. I am trying to remove all occurrences of 08 from the string. However the string is in string format, it just contains an invalid character that corresponds to 08 in hex. I am not sure how to phrase the problem correctly..

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
    NSString * dataString = message.payloadString;
    NSString * wrongCharacter = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c", (char)0x08];
    dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:wrongCharacter withString:@""];
```